# Not able connect: MySQL Connector/J gives me a weird exception

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, tomcat, jdbc

In my web-inf folder I create a class named `com.utilClass.java`.
In this class I have a connection string. It's working in localhost, but when I try to upload on it to hosting, it gives me an error like the following:

> Connection code

```
static public final String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
static public final String connection = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/dilipgodhani?";
static public final String user = "user";
static public final String password = "xxxxx";
Connection con = null;

Class.forName(driver);
con = DriverManager.getConnection(connection, user, password);
Statement st = con.createStatement();
System.out.println(q);
rs = st.executeQuery(q);
```

Comment: sir i am not getting proper solution about that last 3 hours already change ,,,but cant

Answer (score 3):

```
static public final String connection = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/dilipgodhani?"
```

This one works just on localhost.

If you upload your code to a remote host, you should change it to

```
static public final String connection = "jdbc:mysql://REMOTE-HOST-IP:REMOTE-HOST-PORT/dilipgodhani?"
```

Comment: Well, of course it's not enough, but we can't know the parameters of your server. Check username and password as DocJones suggested

Answer (score 2):

It may be that your connection user named "user" on the production machine lacks proper  access rights? Can you do a `mysql -u user` on the production host and log in?